# Can I return to Spain after spending 90 days there?

Tags: schengen, overstaying, visa-free-entry, 90-180-visa-rules

This summer I spent 88 consecutive days in Estepona from June 8th to September 6th. I would like to go back October 31st but I am unsure of the rules. Do I have to be out of the country for 6 months after September 6th or did coming back to Chicago for 2 months satisfy the 180-day law?

Comment: I still don't understand.I arrived in Spain on June 7th,2018,and left Spain on September 6th,2018.Does that mean I have to wait till December 7th,2018 to return to Spain??

Comment: Don't you already have an overstay? June 7th to September 6th is three calendar months, a couple of days over the 90 day limit.

Comment: I entered your dates into the calculator, the result was ‘Days of stay in the 180-days period from 11/03/18 to 06/09/18: 92 day(s)
Overstay in the period from 05/09/18 to 06/09/18 (2 days)

Comment: I think this should be treated as a new question, not a duplicate, because the answers to the possible duplicate do not cover the case of an existing short overstay.

Comment: I'm sorry,I arrived in Spain June 8th,2018,and left Spain September 6th, 2018.That's 90 days.Exactly.When can I return to Spain??

Comment: @Dave Pusateri You still have a 1 day overstay (you have to include the days when you enter and exit). How long do you plan to stay on your next trip?

Comment: 90 more days.I have a parecha de hecho, which means I'm legally living with a woman in Spain,I already have the paperwork, and when I received it at the Town Hall,in Estepona, they said I could stay longer than 90 days.

Comment: @Dave Pusateri Have you already applied for residency? http://spainguru.es/2017/04/09/how-to-apply-for-pareja-de-hecho-civil-union-in-spain/ Please edit your question to include all material information

Answer (score 2):

You have to be out of the country for 90 days after a 90-day stay, because from the date you enter, within the next 180 days the total time in Schengen cannot exceed 90 days.

After those 180 days from your initial entry are up, the clock is reset.

SO you can re-enter on 7 December.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you get a long-stay visa or residence permit from one of the Schengen countries, you cannot enter the area at any time when you have been inside for 90 of the past 180 days.

This means in particular that after spending 90 *consecutive* days on the Schengen area, you need to say outside for 90 entire days before you can enter again.